# Typescript property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have type `User` that can be empty object or object with required fields. In function `getFirstName` I check if object is not empty and then return one of the fields. Then I have error: "Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{}'". Why does it work so?

```
type User =
  | {
      firstName: string;
      age: number;
    }
  | {};

const getFirstName = (currentUser: User) => {
  if (!Object.keys(currentUser).length) {
    return "_";
  }
  return currentUser.firstName; //Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{}'
};

export default function App() {
  const user: User = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    age: 14
  };

  const emptyUser = {};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {getFirstName(user)}</h1>
      <h1>Hello {getFirstName(emptyUser)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-robinson-e29r2?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

1.suggest `Object.keys(currentUser).length <= 0` instead of `!Object.keys(currentUser).length`

2.you need to down cast the union type because property firstName does not exist across multiple type of the union type

```
type User =
  | {
      firstName: string;
      age: number;
    }
  | {};

const getFirstName = (currentUser: User) => {
  if (Object.keys(currentUser).length <= 0) {
    return "_";
  }
  return (currentUser as {
    firstName: string;
    age: number;
  }).firstName;
};

export default function App() {
  const user: User = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    age: 14
  };

  const emptyUser = {};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {getFirstName(user)}</h1>
      <h1>Hello {getFirstName(emptyUser)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: not the same.I went to codesandbox and notice your issue (Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{}'),and I fix it by downcast currentUser.you can not call .firstName because property name firstName is not across multiple type under this union type

Comment: Why not the same?

Comment: @DmitriyGlazkov Did you try my code in CodeSandBox? will the error show again?

Comment: Can u share a link?

Comment: @DmitriyGlazkov Just go to your CodeSandBox Link and replace all you code with mine.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to remove the empty object from the User type (this way you take full advantage of typescript's type checking) and when you encounter an empty object that you know is a User type then just cast it with the `as` keyword.

```
type User = {
      firstName: string;
      age: number;
    };

const getFirstName = (currentUser: User) => {
  if (!Object.keys(currentUser).length) {
    return "_";
  }
  return currentUser.firstName;
};

export default function App() {
  const user: User = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    age: 14
  };

  const emptyUser = {};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {getFirstName(user)}</h1>
      <h1>Hello {getFirstName(emptyUser as User)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But if not set the empty object type to User next developer will use my type and not check that this type is might be empty. And if user come from server, and we don't know empty or not.